# Error: You can't include a backup sub-folder

Tags: backup, backintime

`BackInTime` does not allow me to take snapshots of

```
/home/user/directory
```

and save it in

```
/home/user/backintime/host/user/1.
```

It complains "You can't include a backup sub-folder". I do not see the reason. Is this a bug?

N.B. It allows me to save in `/home/user/other_directory/backintime/host/user/1` (which is an overkill of sub-folder-depth).

Comment: If you take backup of /home/usr/ you will have to store the backup somewhere else than under /home/usr/....

Comment: I am taking backup of /home/user/directory/, so there is no loop.

Comment: @PrimoPetri any odd links the original directory?

Comment: @muru I can reproduce the bug with a fresh new user and Documents as original directory.

Comment: If this bug is still relevant and reproducible please open an Issue at [upstream project](https://github.com/bit-team/backintime) and we will take care of it.